# default value for column in SQL view

Tags: sql, view, default, isnull

I have an SQL view vith many columns.
ID (land parcel ID) ex : 7465-85-7468
Building (ID of a specific building if needed) ex : 102
Room (ID of a specific room if needed) ex : 0023

I have an ID for each row, but for most of the rows, there is not Building ID or Room ID

I'd like to fill the blank rows with '000' for building, and '0000' for Room.

I could Concat these fields in a fourth field (full ID)

It tried to get a default value with "ISNULL", but it didn't work.

**For Now, I have somethins like this**

> ID / Building / Room / Full ID
>
> 7848-05-6956 /   /   /  7848-05-6956--
>
> 6985-26-7485 / 102 / 0000 / 6985-26-7485-102-0000
>
> 7236-12-0145 /   / 0223 / 7236-12-0145--0223

**I'd need this**

> ID / Building / Room / Full ID
>
> 7848-05-6956 / 000  / 0000 / 7848-05-6956-000-0000
>
> 6985-26-7485 / 102 / 0000 / 6985-26-7485-102-0000
>
> 7236-12-0145 / 000 / 0223 / 7236-12-0145-000-0223

Answer (score 5):

If the field is not nullable, the data may be stored as empty strings rather than NULL's.

Try doing something like the following:

```
SELECT x.ID, x.Building, x.Room, ID + '-' + Building + '-' + Room AS [Full ID]
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID
  , CASE WHEN ISNULL(Building, '') = '' THEN '000' ELSE Building END AS Building
  , CASE WHEN ISNULL(Room, '') = '' THEN '0000' ELSE Room END AS Room
  FROM MyTable ) x
```

This will handle both NULL and empty string and it will allow you to build Full ID without executing the CASE statements twice.

Comment: You forgot the ELSE clauses in your CASE statements. If `Building` or `Room` is not null then `NULL` will be returned by the CASE statement. You need `ELSE Building END AS Building` and `ELSE Room END AS Room` respectively

Comment: I just updated it... *slaps forehead* sorry about that! I don't know how I missed that! :)